# crud: How to make name and area change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React trying to make a full crud application, but I can't figure out how to make the name and area for the rooms created in the houses change. Does anyone have any suggestions or know how to make this work?

Also sorry for all the code idk what is needed for people to see.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HousesList } from './Components/Houses-List'
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HousesList/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

House.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NewRoomForm } from './NewRoomForm';
import { EditRoomForm } from './EditRoomForm';

export const House = (props) => {
    const { house, updateHouse } = props;

    const deleteRoom = (roomId) => {
        const updatedHouse = {
            ...house,
            rooms: house.rooms.filter((x) => x._id !== roomId)
        };
        updateHouse(updatedHouse);
    }

    const addNewRoom = (room) => updateHouse({ ...house, rooms: [...house.rooms, room]});

    const rooms = () => (
        <ul>
            {house.rooms.map((room, index) => (
                <li key={index}>
                    <label> {`${room.name} Area: ${room.area}`} </label>
                    <button onClick={(e) => deleteRoom(room._id)}>Delete Room</button>
                    <EditRoomForm />
                    <h1> </h1>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{house.name}</h1>
            {
                rooms({ rooms, houseId: house._id, deleteRoom})
            }
            <NewRoomForm addNewRoom={addNewRoom} />
            {/* <EditRoomForm addNewRoom={addNewRoom} /> */}
        </div>
    )
    
};
```

EditRoomForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';




export const EditRoomForm = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [area, setArea] = useState('');

    const handleAreaInput = (e) => {
        const int = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
        setArea(int >= 0 ? int : '');
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        if (name && area) {

            console.log("name: " + name)
            console.log("area: " + area)

            setName('');
            setArea('');

            console.log("name: " + name)
            console.log("area: " + area)
        } else {
            console.log('invalid input');
        }
    };
        
    return (
        
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <input 
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='name'
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    value={name}
                />
                <input
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='area'
                    onChange={handleAreaInput}
                    value={area}
                />
                <button type='submit'>Edit Room</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
};
```

NewRoomForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';



export const NewRoomForm = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [area, setArea] = useState('');

    const handleAreaInput = (e) => {
        const int = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
        setArea(int >= 0 ? int : '');
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (name && area) {
            props.addNewRoom({name, area});
            setName('');
            setArea('');
        } else {
            console.log('invalid input');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Add a new room</h4>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <input 
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='name'
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    value={name}
                />
                <input
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='area'
                    onChange={handleAreaInput}
                    value={area}
                />
                <button type='submit'>Add/Edit Room</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Houses-List.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { House } from './House';
import { housesApi } from '../rest/HousesApi';
import { NewRoomForm } from './NewRoomForm';
// import { EditRoomForm } from './edit';

export class HousesList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        houses: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Inside componentDidMount Funcaton Block")
        this.fetchHouses();
    }

    fetchHouses = async () => {
        console.log("Inside fetchHouses Funcaton Block")
        const houses = await housesApi.get();
        this.setState({ houses });
    }

    updateHouse = async (updatedHouse) => {
        console.log("Inside updateHouse Funcaton Block")
        console.log("housesApi Check: " + housesApi)
        await housesApi.put(updatedHouse);
        this.fetchHouses();
    };

    render() {
        console.log("Inside render of Houses-List")
        console.log(this.state.houses);
        return (
            <div className="house-list">
                
                {this.state.houses.map((house) => (
                    <House 
                        house={house}
                        key={house._id}
                        updateHouse={this.updateHouse}
                    />
                ))}
            <NewRoomForm /> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

HousesApi.js

```
const HOUSES_ENDPOINT = "https://ancient-taiga-31359.herokuapp.com/api/houses";

class HousesApi {
    get = async () => {
        try {
            console.log("Inside Try Block Of HousesAPI get funcation")
            const resp = await fetch(HOUSES_ENDPOINT);
            const data = await resp.json();
            return data;
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("Oops, looks like fetchHouses has an issue", e)
        }
    }

    put = async (house) => {
        try {
            console.log("Inside Try Block Of put funcation")
            console.log(house)
            console.log("HOUSES_ENDPOINT: " + HOUSES_ENDPOINT + house._id)
            console.log("house._id: " + house._id)
            
            const resp = await fetch(`${HOUSES_ENDPOINT}/${house._id}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(house)
            });

            console.log("The body is: " + JSON.stringify(house))
            // console.log(" resp.json(): " +  resp.json())
            console.log("At The End OF Try Block Of put funcation")
            return await resp.json();
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("Oops, looks like updating houses has an issue", e)
        }
    }
}


export const housesApi = new HousesApi();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before helping on the code, I will explain the concept on updating the rooms based on your code structure.

1. The EditRoomForm needs to rendered with selected room props and curried function with index parameter.
2. The EditRoomForm has its own state of room which will be updated when there is an incoming selected room props by using `useEffect`.
3. User updates the name and area and click submit which will trigger a callback function props which will send back the new name and area and update those new name and area by using index inside the `house.rooms`.
4. Parent `House.js` will call the house API `PUT` method with updated details.

With the steps above, you will need to update your code like this.

**House.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NewRoomForm } from './NewRoomForm';
import { EditRoomForm } from './EditRoomForm';

export const House = (props) => {
    const { house, updateHouse } = props;

    const deleteRoom = (roomId) => {
        const updatedHouse = {
            ...house,
            rooms: house.rooms.filter((x) => x._id !== roomId)
        };
        updateHouse(updatedHouse);
    }
     
    const updateRoom = (index) => (name,area) => {
        const updatingHouse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(house));
        updatingHouse.rooms[index] = {...updatingHouse.rooms[index], name,area}
        updateHouse(updatingHouse );
    }


    const addNewRoom = (room) => updateHouse({ ...house, rooms: [...house.rooms, room]});

    const rooms = () => (
        <ul>
            {house.rooms.map((room, index) => (
                <li key={index}>
                    <label> {`${room.name} Area: ${room.area}`} </label>
                    <button onClick={(e) => deleteRoom(room._id)}>Delete Room</button>
                    <EditRoomForm selectedRoom={room} onSubmit={updateRoom(index)} />
                    <h1> </h1>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{house.name}</h1>
            {
                rooms({ rooms, houseId: house._id, deleteRoom})
            }
            <NewRoomForm addNewRoom={addNewRoom} />
        </div>
    )
    
};
```

**EditRoomForm.js**

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';


export const EditRoomForm = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [area, setArea] = useState('');
    const {selectedRoom} = props;

    useEffect(() => {
      setName(selectedRoom.name); 
      setArea(selectedRoom.area); 
    }, [selectedRoom] )

    const handleAreaInput = (e) => {
        const int = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
        setArea(int >= 0 ? int : '');
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        if (name && area) {

            console.log("name: " + name)
            console.log("area: " + area)
            props.onSubmit(name,area);

            setName('');
            setArea('');

            console.log("name: " + name)
            console.log("area: " + area)
        } else {
            console.log('invalid input');
        }
    };
        
    return (
        
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <input 
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='name'
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    value={name}
                />
                <input
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='area'
                    onChange={handleAreaInput}
                    value={area}
                />
                <button type='submit'>Edit Room</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
};
```

You get the idea.

Comment: I put the code you provided into mine and it basically just showed me the name and area within the text boxes below., also thanks for the explanation I'm pretty new to using react and coding in general so half the time I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: no worries...glad to help you ...so did i answer your question?

Comment: Well what I was trying to say is that when I placed your code into mine it just made the texted boxes under the rooms show the name and area they had and when I type something else nothing happened.

Comment: you have onChange handlers right, when you type the new names they did change yeah? and then when you try to submit the button, what will happen? does it call API with new detail?

Comment: No, when I press submit it after changing the name and area, it removes the new name and area I typed and puts the old name and area back within the text bock while not changing the real name or area of the room.

Comment: my bad..should be  <EditRoomForm selectedRoom={room} onSubmit={updateRoom(index)} /> ...edited again.. please check my codesandbox also which is working https://codesandbox.io/s/house-editor-ej3yo?file=/src/App.js  pretty clumsy when i'm rushing to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button and use useState hook to keep the state. On button click set the `editingRoom` state to true. On state change the component will be re-rendered and EditForm component will be shown. You need to pass proper props. And once editing is completed please reset the editingRoom state to false.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const [editingRoom, setEditingRoom] = useState(false);

const handleEditRoom = (room) => {
   .......
   setEditingRoom(false);
}

const rooms = () => (
        <ul>
            {house.rooms.map((room, index) => (
                <li key={index}>
                    <label> {`${room.name} Area: ${room.area}`} </label>
                    <button onClick={(e) => deleteRoom(room._id)}>Delete Room</button>
{!editingRoom && <button onClick={(e) => seEditingRoom(true)}>Edit Room</button>}
                    {editingRoom && <EditRoomForm handleEditRoom={handleEditRoom} />}
                    <h1> </h1>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
```